# Выборка из БД значений определенного столбца без повторов?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в Базе данных, в ней есть колонка "ДЕНЬ", а в базе данных, к примеру, 10 строк, и значения у этих строк в колонке "ДЕНЬ" примерно таковы:

```
3,3,4,5,5,5,8,10,10,15
```

Есть ли способ составить такой запрос, чтобы шла выборка значений этой колонки, но чтобы исключались повторения значений - то есть массив выборки должен представлять собой

```
3,4,5,8,10,15
```

Надеюсь, я правильно смог растолковать задачку.

Решение у меня есть, но оно получилось слишком громоздкое.

Если такое возможно сделать одним запросом, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как его составить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ДЕНЬ FROM table_name
```

Ключевое слово DISTINCT позволит выбрать только неповторяющиеся значения.

Comment: Спасибо большое то что надо!